# How do you Spell: Smused? Smoosed?

Tags: spelling-pronunciations

How do you Spell: Smused, Smoosed?

As in: "Bill Smused the clients. Warming them up for the spiel from marketing."

Comment: The word you're looking for is probably "smooched".  ;)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I'll throw a guess you want [schmooze](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/schmooze) (or *shmooze* as a spelling variant):

> to talk with someone in a friendly way often in order to get some advantage for yourself

(From Merriam Webster)

Comment: Yes, that is it. Thank you. Google was not helping at all. And I am really surprised that it did not turn up in any the the synonym for "amuse" lists that I looked at.

Comment: Note that "schmooze" is intransitive: the usage is "Bill schmoozed ***with*** the clients, warming them up for the spiel from marketing."

Comment: ... though it looks like Merriam-Webster lists a transitive usage for it, too, but that sounds Totally Wrong to my ear.

Comment: "Schmooze" is not related to "amuse," and the two words' meanings are pretty different.  That's why you didn't find it in a list of synonyms for "amuse."

Comment: @Marthaª I hear "schmoozed the client" more often than "schmoozed *with* the client"...maybe a local preference?

Comment: Ya, "schmoozed the client" is, I believe, the only way I have ever heard the word used. It is an action to be performed on someone.

Comment: I sort of thought. Schmooze is sort of like amusing someone for advantage. If you boss tells you to amuse the potential clients, is just leaving out the implied part of you trying to get some sort of business/personal advantage.

Comment: Is no one going to mention that this is a Yiddishism?